# How to create HexRays variables in IDAPython correctly?

Tags: idapython, hexrays

Let's assume we have a function which has a following variables in it:

- Local variables on stack of different types, including types defined in local types window
- Local variables of different types mapped to registers
- Function parameters of different types

I have 2 IDBs with the same function based on the same binary and I want to pass this data from one IDB to another.
Let's also assume that I have a solution of passing related data types between databases.

I know that I can iterate the local variables in decompiled function by using  user_lvar_visitor_t class. 
I also know that there is a function save_user_lvar_settings these variables by using of the same iterator class user_lvar_visitor_t.

I have the following questions regarding this:

- Which data should I gather from the first database to create these variables in second database correctly (with IDAPython, IDA version is 6.8)?
- How can I create these variables in the second database to make use of save_user_lvar_settings or restore_user_lvar settings (with IDAPython, IDA version is 6.8)?

Update: Before asking this question I reviewed the following IDA collaboration solutions:

1. Collabreate
2. ida2sql
3. IDA toolbag
4. IDAsynergy
5. IDAsync

One more update

6. Diaphora

And was not able to find solution for my problem in any them.

Comment: Not an answer but maybe of help: ida2sql, see https://github.com/zynamics/ida2sql-plugin-ida. You could have a look at how they treat variables. This may help you, at least, with the first question.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not working with hexrays related data. However you are right, I had to update my question with a list of packages I reviewed before asking this question.

Comment: Maybe [Diaphora](https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) ? They do use the HexRays data when comparing databases.

Comment: @tmr232 Yes, they use HexRays, but I was unable to find how they passing local variables between databases. As far as I can see, they comparing 2 hex-rays decompilations on a base of AST tree comparison.